# Android Application Crash Only on Device

Tags: android, crash

My application runs absolutely fine on the Android Emulator but when I install the apk file in the tablet device and install it and then run it, the application crashes, giving an error message that **The application(process.my.package.name) has stopped**.

LogCat says that isEmpty() on String is not defined (but it shows no error during compilation).

My minSdk version in the manifest file is 8 but my application is 4.0.3 and my application runs absolutely fine on the Emulator. It crashes only on the device. I am totally clueless as what could the reason possibly be as it works perfectly fine on the emulator.

Any suggestions/ideas would be really helpful.

Comment: what error description you get in your log cat

Comment: give more info on what your app deals with and what you r doing in the main page of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logcat to extract information.

Usual differences between device and emulator include:

- GPS position
- network availability and latency
- availability of "extended storage" (some tablets only have internal memory, no extended one)

G'd luck with the bug hunt

Answer (score 1):

You should try to check out the configuration that you have done in the emulator... specially in manifest file.HTH